# how to disable auto table creation in Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring boot with hibernate and JPA .I don't want my Spring boot app to auto create tables in my DB. I tried following but still not working for me and tables are generated.

```
#DB PROPERTIES
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#HIBERNATE AND JPA PROPERTIES
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: Have you placed these properties file under correct folder like `src/main/resources`. Also, check if these properties are not overridden subsequently by another properties file in your codebase.

Comment: Check if you have application.properties in classpath which is overriding this

Comment: thanks ....the issue was property was overridden